# Inserting user ip address into database using prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

How do i insert user ip address into my database using prepared statement?

I have tried this 2 codes, 1 which i got from a question asked here but i do get an empty column (i.e. the user ip address is not inserted into my database).

**First code i worked with;**

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // grab users ip address
$insert = "INSERT INTO users_signup_ip(ip_address) VALUES(?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $insert);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $ip);
if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
   # code...
}
```

**Second code i worked with (current);**

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // grab users ip address
$insert = "INSERT INTO users_signup_ip(ip_address) VALUES(INET_ATON(?))";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_var, $insert);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $ip);
if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
   # code...
}
```

Comment: Check for errors. Does the execute return true?

Comment: no...... @Qirel

Comment: You should read up on [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). That will help you find out _why_ the query fails.

Comment: `echo mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);` for the statement objects. Do not inject the variable directly in the query as the answer below suggested. It might work, but will not be secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following method

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users_signup_ip(ip_address) VALUES (?)");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$stmt->bind_param("s", $ip);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Wrap the code in try catch block so if there is an exception you will get to know

Comment: As far as I know, mysqli doesn't throw any exceptions if the statement fails, which makes try/catch moot.

Comment: **Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\signup.php on line 215** @FaizanFayaz

Comment: `$insert = "INSERT INTO users_signup_ip(ip_address) VALUES(?)"; $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_var, $insert);`

Comment: After that code write the following for checking the error.  print_r(mysqli_error($db_var));

Comment: i did a mistake when typing thats why, but everything now works fine @FaizanFayaz

Comment: Just a little thing, you don't need to copy `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to `$ip` to use it, just use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` directly with `bind_param()`, by copying you are using unnecessary memory.